# Docker: unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in context path: readlink C:\Users\fred.blogs\My Documents: Access is denied

Tags: docker

I have just installed Docker Toolbox on Windows 7.

When I try and run:

```
docker build -t phpinfo .
```

I get:

```
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in context path: readlink
 C:\Users\fred.blogs\My Documents: Access is denied.
```

My Dockerfile is correctly named without an extension.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work, by moving to a different folder.